# ttk progress bar stops whilst running sql query within GUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

I'm building a GUI which at some point(s) will query a SQL database. Whilst the query is running, I wanted to show the user an indeterminate progress bar (ttk) which would indicate this. See below for simple example.

```
from Function_Sheet import *
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
root = Tk()

s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('clam')
s.configure('red.Horizontal.TProgressbar', foreground='red', background='red')
mpb2 = ttk.Progressbar(root,style='red.Horizontal.TProgressbar', orient ='horizontal', length = 200, mode ='indeterminate')
mpb2.pack()
mpb2.start(1)
print 'query not done'
cursor = SolvittConnect(<SQL HERE>)
print 'query done'
root.mainloop()
```

Unfortunatley the query seems to run even before the root window is loaded.

How can I show the moving progress bar **WHILST** the query is being executed?

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `tkinter` to draw anything, it must be in the mainloop. The mainloop is exactly as it sounds- an infinite loop which handles events. As such, commands after the mainloop are not done until the mainloop completes.

To solve your issue, you need to setup the SQL query to happen in the mainloop while the GUI updates. Do this by setting up an `after` call- it will be a lambda probably, so this is a good time to swap to classes, since they allow you to call a method from an after and that method can set a class variable

```
class ...
    ...
    def __init__(self):
        root=Tk()
        ...
        mpb2.start(1)
        root.after(1000, # in milliseconds
                   lambda *e: self.connect())   
        root.mainloop()
        ...
    def connect(self):
        print "querying"
        self.cursor = SolvittConnect(<SQL>)
        print "query complete"
```

Note that your SolvittConnect will probably stop the GUI from updating- look into throwing that to a thread or a worker pool, since the GUI can't update while python is executing a function (unless there are explicit calls during execution, but SolvittConnect doesn't explicitly tell the GUI to update while it tries to connect)

Comment: Thanks @Delioth, I know I need to brush up on my classes! However isnt my SolvittConnect function within the mainloop? Why does the SolvittConnect call happen before the window or progressbar is packed?

Comment: It isn't happening before they are packed, it's happening before they are displayed- outside of a mainloop (or the Tcl interpreter getting some idle time where it happens to update) Tk cannot draw/redraw - Tk knows it needs to draw things, it just can't display anything because it doesn't have any updates on the stack - if you were to put a `root.update_idletasks()` before your SQL piece, the window and all would display before the query. It would still stop/be unresponsive during the query, however.

Comment: So if I tell the progress bar to update within the SolvittConnect function that will solve this problem? I will need to call the update method over and over?

Comment: It will help, but it may not work perfectly (i.e. while your connection is trying and blocking all python code, it won't update unless you thread it or pool it). Note that you should use the `update_idletasks` function instead of the `update` function- it's safer (`update` creates an arbitrarily-long event loop, so if there's the chance to call another `update` it can give you a long stack of event loops. `_idletasks` doesn't execute events, it's for redrawing and other things that usually only happen while idle)

Comment: @Luke.py if this answer helped you, consider [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)